# Authentication with Soap service in C# console

Tags: c#, soap, console, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to connect to a soap service(wsdl) from the console in C#.
My code is fairly simple, I added the wsdl to the project as a service reference, and the proxy class(?) was created as expected.

The service use a authentication key per message, and i cannot find anywhere to add it to the soap header.
As a reference, this is the code i run inside my main method:

```
Api.Servicereference1.PortClient object = new Api.Servicereference1.PortClient();                        
object.testmethod();
```

The output from this piece is the following:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <testmethod xmlns="http://wsdlserver.com/soap"/>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However, what i want to achive is the following message sent, with the authentication:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <s:auth>key</s:auth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">        
        <testmethod xmlns="http://wsdlserver.com/soap"/>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Can anyone help me in the right direction, as to how I can add this custom header to my messages?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for the input,I did some reading, and figured that if I surround my message with an *OperationContextScope* I am able to add headers as I please.
I changed my code to:

```
Api.Servicereference1.PortClient object = new Api.Servicereference1.PortClient();
using ( OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(object.InnerChannel))
{
     MessageHeader soapheader = MessageHEader.CreateHeader("name","ns",payload);
     OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(soapheader);
     object.testmethod();
}
```

The parameters in *MessageHeader.CreateHeader()* is explained here [MessageHeader.CreateHeader Method (String, String, Object) from msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195413.aspx)

Although this solution would require me to manually add an OperationContext to all my messages, it solves the issue of custom soapheaders for me.

Answer (score 1):

Article on how to add custom headers to WCF client proxies:

[Adding custom headers to every WCF call - a solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2006/04/26/Adding-custom-headers-to-every-WCF-call-_2D00_-a-solution.aspx)